# How to Disable Click on a radio button without disabling it in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Requirement** : 
I want to 'disable Click of a radio button' using JQuery. The radio button will be already checked, before click.

**Conditions**:

1) The disable attribute should not be set to true. Means we must not radio button to make click disable on it.

2) If user clicks on that radio button, then it should not get unchecked.

**Why Such Requirement**:
A Common JQuery is already written for onClick of all Radios in form. I want it not to get executed at all for particular radio.

As I do not have authority to change that jQuery. That JQuery enable disable some other elements on form on clicking of radio.

so i need to handle that in my Jquery either onload or some other method. I hope requirements are clear. Please help!!

**Update**:
From Answers i have created three fiddle but none worked yet.

```
1) https://jsfiddle.net/uhxpmexe/ 
2) https://jsfiddle.net/ry5zqcv7/
3) https://jsfiddle.net/k0gd57ks/
```

Looking, If someone can contribute more

Comment: Do you mean that you do not want people to be able to change the value in the radio buttons, but also do not want them to be disabled?

Comment: Right. Do not want to Disable the Radio and do not want user to click it. If clicked and also do not want the common jquery to get executed at all (which gets executed on click).

Answer (score 2):

I think you are asking "How can I remove an event handler from a specific radio button after some other code (which I don't have access to) adds the handler to all radio buttons in my form?"

If this is correct, you could simply give your radio an `id` and then call: `$( "#myRadio").unbind( "click" );`

Comment: What about when selecting the option by the keyboard?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan  I feel like all the OP wants is to disable the click handler that some other code adds to his radio along with the others on the form, not actually disable the radio itself at all, maybe Im wrong though

Comment: Let me test whether it works for my case, as other Common jquery for radio, which execute on radio click, changes other elements in form.

Comment: @DelightedD0D
Sorry, it is not working for me. Here's link: https://jsfiddle.net/uhxpmexe/

Comment: @fatherazrael You'll need to add the code after the handler is added like this https://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/uhxpmexe/1/ , in your actual page just make sure your js file is loaded after the one that adds the unwanted handler

Comment: Great. It is working fine in fiddle; but let me take the same in my solution because i need to unbind and bind at a few instances. If it worked well then it will be an answer for me. If you find some more alternative do suggest. Thanks.

Comment: @fatherazrael Should do the trick, just make sure you unbind after the other code and that you add your new handlers after the call to `unbind` : )

Comment: @DelightedD0D: 
Other Click code will get executed and will call a method which i can access and i will unbind click during that Click on condition and then rebind it again on else condition, so that it can work on few instances, where click again is required.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77693/discussion-between-fatherazrael-and-delightedd0d).

Answer (score 2):

You can simply return false in click handler:

```
 $(":radio").click( function(){
         return false;
 });
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vhxpqp47/)**

Update: As you have already defined click handler, you need to unbind it and then add new click handler which returns false:

```
$("#ba").unbind('click').click( function(){
     return false;
 });
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kdfu12s2/)**

Comment: What about when selecting the option by the keyboard?

Comment: Let me test whether it works for my case, as other Common jquery for radio, which execute on radio click, changes other elements in form.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar

Sorry it is not working for me. Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k0gd57ks/

Comment: Why have you defined 2 handlers??

Comment: In JQuery, i already have two onclick handlers as mentioned in question. One belong to mine and other is already there. I have removed click attribute from input tag which i placed by mistake. Still it does not work.

Comment: It seems like the OP is adding something to some page and isnt allowed to change the original code

Answer (score 0):

Just use `event.preventDefault()` [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/er5v40a6/)

Comment: What about when selecting the option by the keyboard?

Comment: The question is about `I want to 'disable Click of a radio button' using JQuery`, not selecting it.

Comment: The OP doesn't have access to edit the jQuery that adds the original handler to the element so I don't believe this would work for them

Comment: Let me test whether it works for my case, as other Common jquery for radio, which execute on radio click, changes other elements in form.

Comment: @fatherazrael - you can use e.stopPropagation() but you would have to use it on specific radio buttons - I mean declare those, which event shouldn't be propagated.

Comment: @Kamo
Could you please edit above fiddle and show its implementation?

Answer (score 0):

`pointer-events: none;` should do the trick. With addClass in jQuery you can add it any time

```
.disabled{
    cursor: not-allowed; /* aesthetics */
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Also check out: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/pointer-events/

Comment: Thanks. But i gues it will not disable click on Radio? Let me test whether it works for my case, as other Common jquery for radio, which execute on radio click, changes other elements in form.

Comment: Thanks. Looking pretty good. Let me try and will come back if any issue.

Comment: It is not working in IE-10, IE-11 and working fine in Mozilla Firefox. Client is IE so i could not opt :(. Any alternative?

Comment: It Should work in IE11+ according to the link i've added. If you need to support it ofc it's not optimal. Why aren't you allowed to use `disabled="true"` if i might ask?

Comment: Because i have to submit that value to server. there are many such values, not want to enable it during submits, much of coding is done, these are few bugs for which i do not want to get into major refactoring

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code for disabled the radio button.

`$(".example").attr('disabled','disabled');`

Please let me know if code working for you.